# How can I install a new class in my existing LaTeX?

Tags: installing

Currently I have a very old version (2nd edition 1994) IEEE standard LaTeX but now I need to run the Royal Society open science standard LaTeX on Windows7. They supplied 3 files in their template named

`rsos.cls`, `Author_tex.tex`, and `Instruction.tex`

Where do I put them so that they can be used in my documents?

Comment: the easiest way is simply to put `rsos.cls` and the other files in the same folder as your document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You don't say what OS you are using.  See the following questions, which yours is a duplicate of: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/2693)